# Changing the default seaborn heatmap plots

Tags: python, latex, seaborn

I have exported a large Matrix from Matlab to a `data.dat` file, which is tab delimited. I am importing this data into a iPython script to use `seaborn` to create a heatmap of the matrix using the following MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

uniform_data = np.loadtxt("data.dat", delimiter="\t")
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, linewidth=0.0)
plt.show()
```

This code runs fine and outputs a correct heatmap, generating the following output:

[image: latex]

How can I change the style of this output? Specifically, I would like to change the colour scheme and also have the fonts in LaTeX form. This is since I would like to export this output as a .pdf file and import into a LaTeX document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can control the color scheme with the `cmap` key of `sns.heatmap()`. See [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html) for what color maps are available.
2. Generally to make all fonts in a plot look like latex fonts you can do

`sns.set(rc={'text.usetex': True})`

What it does is adding a `$` around each text object in the plot to allow the underlying tex environment to "tex-ify" it. This works fine for the colorbar but, as you can see [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1363), there seems to be a (to me still unresolved bug) making it not working for axes ticklabels. As a workaround you can manually add `$` around all tick labels to allow the tex interpreter recognize it as tex again à la

```
# Collecting all xtick locations and labels and wrapping the labels in two '$'
plt.xticks(plt.xticks()[0], ['$' + label._text + '$' for label in plt.xticks()[1]])
```

So for demonstrating your example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

# Use tex for all labels globally in the plot
sns.set(rc={'text.usetex': True})

uniform_data = np.random.rand(30, 30)

# Adjust colormap with the cmap key (here 'cubehelix')
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, linewidth=0.0, cmap='cubehelix')

# workaround wrap '$' around tick labels for x and y axis
# commenting the following two lines makes only the colorbar in latex font
plt.xticks(plt.xticks()[0], ['$' + label._text + '$' for label in plt.xticks()[1]])
plt.yticks(plt.yticks()[0], ['$' + label._text + '$' for label in plt.yticks()[1]])

plt.show()
```

leads to

[image]